# How to prevent from accidental empty S3 bucket operation from AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to prevent any users(even admin) from performing the action of Emptying S3 Bucket which can delete all the objects at once. Though I have configured the bucket policy as -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyDeleteBucket",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy doesn't allow the deletion of the bucket objects directly.
But I'm able to perform the Empty bucket action and delete all the objects.

Note: I am facing this issue after enabling bucket versioning. Even after suspending the versioning, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: There is no API to empty a bucket. Emptying a bucket is effectively deleting the last-remaining object. You seem to be trying to prevent the deletion of *any* object.

Comment: Right! There is no API. But there is an option in the AWS console to empty the Bucket. Please search for empty button in AWS S3 console, you'd got it.

Comment: The point is that the 'Empty Bucket' button in the AWS Console is simply issuing a series of DeleteObject or DeleteObjects requests. There is no 'empty bucket' API that a client can call or that you can control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce your situation I did the following:

- Logged in as an **IAM User** with Administrator permissions
- Created a **new Amazon S3 bucket**
- Added your **Bucket Policy** (only changing the bucket name)
- Uploaded a file to the bucket
- Attempted to **Delete** the object

I received the error message: `Failed to delete objects`

- Selected the bucket and clicked **Empty**

I received the error message: `Failed to empty bucket`

I then **signed out of the console** and signed in again using my **root credentials**.

- I navigated to the S3 console, selected the bucket and clicked **Empty**

I received the error message: `Failed to empty bucket`

- I attempted to delete the object I uploaded earlier

I received the error message: `Failed to delete objects`

- I **removed the bucket policy**
- Selected the bucket and clicked **Empty**

It **successfully deleted** the object from the bucket.

**Findings**

The bucket policy works as you desired. Even as the "root user" I was unable to delete the object or empty the bucket while the policy was in place.

**UPDATE: Versioned Buckets**

When Versioning is enabled on the bucket, you will also need to block `DeleteObjectVersion`.

Comment: Hi John! Thanks for your quick reply and your effort. When I am checking with a different bucket, it's working as expected.
But I am really surprised that why this is not behaving the same with the bucket(after which I raised this question). I tried doing the same more than 10 times, it's behaving erroneously.

Comment: Hello John! When I am enabling the versioning, I am not able to prevent the emptying bucket. 
Please repeat your steps with versioning enabled.

Comment: Ah, most interesting! If the bucket has **Versioning activated**, then it appears that you will also need to Deny the `DeleteObjectVersion` action. From [DeleteObject - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html): _"If you want to block users or accounts from removing or deleting objects from your bucket, you must deny them the `s3:DeleteObject`, `s3:DeleteObjectVersion`, and `s3:PutLifeCycleConfiguration` actions."_

Comment: Thanks. Now it prevents emptying the bucket. But now I cannot restore the old version by deleting the current version.
Is there any other method as well so that I can do the single operation of deleting object but not the bulk operation of deleting all at once ?

Comment: I doubt it. The "Empty" button is probably just triggering code that lists the contents of the bucket and calls `DeleteObject` or `DeleteObjectVersion` using the permissions of the current user. If they can delete an object manually, then they can use the 'Empty' button. One 'cheat' method of restoring a previous version is to copy that version back to the object, so the copy becomes the 'current version'. I used to be able to do that in the console, not sure if it is still supported since the S3 console was updated.

Comment: Right! Copying the version back is the only option for restoring the files and it's working.